# relationship between entities in c#, necessary?

Tags: entity-framework, oop, entity-relationship, object-oriented-database

Regarding the topic, some entities have multiplicity relationship

I learned all of these in my studies, however, is it necessary to maintain in c# programming such as using Entity framework in this example ? :

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-1

this is because I am confused on how the updating of entities works, such as cascading and why it's important.

I find it easier to just code the entity being independent with each other despite the fact they are actually related in real life such as category-product.

can anyone briefly show how CRUD works with this relationship in questions?

Comment: pointing to an article is good (but it's waste of time for us to try to guess from that) but better would be to give us a small example that best illustrates what you need explained

Comment: I would like to know how CRUD operations work with Entity Framework or Object Oriented Programming as my database or class designs practise usually never have any relationships with any of the other entities. For example, Invoice and InvoiceItem class although related as parent and child, I never had them linked together in database via diagram nor linked them up in code level. Because of that, i have to write 2 delete statements just to delete these 2 items. From my understanding as mentioned by derSteve below, with the relationship, deleting Invoice will also delete InvoiceItem via pk/fk.

Comment: You can indeed define an association to cascade the delete to an orphan entity. See this last paragraph on that topic on that msdn page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373856.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework with its entities and their associations between each others gives you the advantage that the framework itself - the OR - Mapper - takes care of all the updates, deletes and inserts for you. It takes care of maintaining the relationships between the entities and the entities itself. You 'just' need to define the model.

You can always go the manual road and code all that yourself. But in most cases defining the entities with their properties and relations between them and having Entity Framework or any other OR-Mapper (like nHibernater) take care of all that, is a huge plus in terms of development speed, maintainability and consistency.

If you define your entities separate from each other - with other words, you do not work with associations between them - you can not navigate from one object to the other. See the example:

**Example a) with associations defined:**

2 entities: order and orderitem
One order can have up to n order items. You can traverse/navigate from the specific order to all associated order items, e.g.

```
var myOrder = Repository.FindOrderById(15);
var orderItems = myorder.OrderItems;
```

**Example b) without associations defined:**

2 entities: order and orderitem
Without associations defined, you can not navigate from one entity to another. You would need to query for all order items separately, e.g.

```
var myOrder = Respository.FindOrderById(15);
var orderItems = Repository.FindOrderItemsByOrder(15);
```

This is not saying how the entities are loaded. In example b, to query the order and the related order items, the OR-Mapper executes 2 queries against the database. In example a, you could define whether to *lazy load* the entities in 2 queries or to *eager load* in 1 query. Having defined associations give you the option to choose whether to load related entities *eagerly* or *lazy*.

This is a good starting point for Entity Framework in general:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx

That is a good overview how relationships between entities work and what options you have:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373856.aspx

Comment: right now, I am using and learning to use Entity Framework. As you said, EF handles CRUD for me, automatically. However I am not sure how the relationship between entities works during CRUD with EF and how important or necessary entity relationship is with CRUD.

Comment: so when the items are linked, such as 1..*, query parent will cascade query the child entity as well ? what about other operations such as delete, update and  add

Comment: see my changes above. What do you want to know about delete, update and add? Have a look at the links first. They should give you a solid understanding. There is no need to repeat msdn articles here.